# Cleanest method for creating a pytest test fixture that takes in dynamic text data

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have class that takes in text data when its instantiated, and also contains parsing methods that search for host name, and data center info within the text data:

```
class SystemConfig:
  def __init__(self, text_data):
    self.text_data = text_data

  def get_server(self):
    match = re.search('.+ (server.+?)', self.text_data, re.S)
    if match:
      return match.group(1)

  def get_datacenter(self):
    match = re.search('.+? (dc.+?)', self.text_data, re.S)
    if match:
      return match.group(1)
```

I am trying to identify the most efficient way for writing pytest fixtures for this.

The route I am heading down is as follows:

```
@pytest.fixture
def server_data():
  return SystemConfig('row 1 rack 2 server001')

@pytest.fixture
def datacenter_data():
  return SystemConfig('row 1 rack 2 dc001')

def test_server_data(server_data):
  assert server_data.get_server() == 'server001'

def test_server_data(server_data):
  assert server_data.get_datacenter() == 'dc001'
```

Instantiating a class each time I need to tweak the text data seems inefficient to me. I may need to write 20 more parsing methods to grab specific text entries.

Any guidance on the best way to to write test fixtures for this is much appreciated.

Please also let me know if you need any further clarification. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems odd to structure the original class such that the regex parsing is done for the `get` methods (which are unpythonic in themselves) - you re-parse the string every time the method is called. Why not implement a *class method* (e.g. `SystemConfig.from_string`) that does the parsing, instead? The `__init__` then takes e.g. `row`, `rack`, `server` and `datacenter` parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Jon. To further clarify, the output comes from a file. So there is a wrapper (that I should have listed) that opens the file, reads the file data into a variable, and then the class gets instantiated with that data. The file itself has various entries, and other interesting data that needs to be parsed out. So my main issue is that everything is not row rack server dc :-(. Since I am trying to do TDD, I am more or less looking for a starting point. The config file itself is not consistent, so I have to rely on keywords, and positional entries to extract what I need.

Comment: What *I believe* you are after is caleld [Parametizing fixtures and test functions](https://pytest.org/latest/parametrize.html)

Comment: I'm not sure that conflicts with what I'm saying. Once you get the code working, consider taking it over to http://codereview.stackexchange.com for some feedback.

Comment: James. Thanks for providing this, I believe this gets me in the right direction. Question I have is.. Is it better to use bogus output, and supplement the test case with the exact text I want to parse with something like stringIO? Basically decoupling the value required by __init__ , and the actual text I would need to parse?  I'm afraid if I have 15 more methods, the params list could get quite long. I was hoping there might be a best practice for this particular use case.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't agree with you. I am missing something for sure :-) The scenario I have is: I have a 500 line file. There are 50 variations of uniqueness I am accounting for. I am searching for keywords and essentially  grabbing the word next to the keyword. I have about 15 more entry types I need to parse. Those other 15 entries each have about 4-8 values I need to extract. i.e. app (some application) server (server name ) ip (ipaddress). I could put the keywords in init. However, it would be about 120 vars. Albeit, I could probably break this up somehow.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I figured I could read in the whole file, and parse it. Being that having the whole thing in mem could be faster. Subsequently, I am trying to figure out the proper way to test this. I could create a class with a default var of None, and then use stringIO to supply the needed text. I could mock out a file, and write the text I need on a per module basis to that fixture, or I could create a test fixture that instantiates a class with text for each test case. Trying to figure out if there is a best practice here, and what others have used.

Comment: @jonsharpe I meant to say I don't disagree with you.. Sorry :-)

Comment: Without much more information it's hard to give a sensible answer. It sounds like each instance corresponds to multiple lines from the file, each with various values to extract. Is that right? Or is one line one instance? Should they really all be the same class?

Comment: @jonsharpe Its the former. Each instance has multiple lines from which I have to extract values. I feel at the end of the day I need to construct a parsing tree, or find a lib. I stumbled upon a lib called parsimonious which may be my answer. If I go this route, I have a clear path for how I will construct my test cases. I feel you are right in that there is no clear answer here. Looking at parsimonious, it looks like the writer supplies a small amount of text when he instantiates the class for his test cases. Others use files. I think a parsing lib is really what I need.

Comment: @jonsharpe I appreciate the feedback. Your challenges and dialogue have led me to this conclusion.. :-) I would +1 your feedback if I could.